# Fréchet's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-measure

Let $(\Bbb R,\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*,\bar\lambda)$ be the complete Lebesgue measure space. Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be a function. Fréchet's theorem states that:

$$f\in M(\Bbb R,\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*)\Leftrightarrow\exists\;\text{a sequence of continuous functions}\;\;(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\;\text{s.t.}\;\;f_n\to f\;a.e.-\bar\lambda$$

Proof: $\mid\Rightarrow)$ part
Let's assume $f\in M(\Bbb R,\mathcal A_{\Bbb R}^*)$, by [Lusin's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559933/complete-lusins-theorem),we get that:

$$\forall n\in\Bbb N\;\exists\;E_n\;\text{open, with}\;\bar\lambda(E_n)<\frac{1}{n},\;\ \text{s.t.}\;\;f_n=f\mid_{E_n^c}\;\;\text{is continuous}$$

so letting $N=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}E_n$ we get that $\bar\lambda(N)=0$ but know got stuck trying to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\;\forall x\in\Bbb R\setminus N$.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that $f_n$ is only defined on the complement of $E_n$.

Comment: But I still don't get how this could help. The only thing I got so far is that, since $x\in\Bbb R\setminus N \Rightarrow\ \exists\ n_0\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $x\in\Bbb R\setminus E_{n_0}$ but can't see anything from here.

Comment: My comment was not intended to be a hint. First you should try to extend $f_n$ continuously to $\mathbb{R}$. For proving the theorem, it is helpful to consider a decreasing sequence $E_n$, i.e., $E_{n+1} \subset E_n$.